# Converting column value from varchar to integer in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to return all rows where the sv column, a varchar, is greater than 40. How can I convert sv to an integer on the fly.
The line below returns ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "SV"

```
SELECT namefirst, namelast, yearid FROM pitching JOIN people ON pitching.playerID = people.playerID WHERE CAST(sv AS INTEGER)>40;
```

Comment: Why are you storing a number as a string?  Can you provide sample values?

Comment: I just copied from an existing csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have a built-in way to avoid conversion errors.  One method is to use a `case` expression:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN sv ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN sv::integer END) > 40
```

Or, if the integers are zero padded on the left, then you might be able to use string comparisons:

```
WHERE sv >= '40'
```

However, this runs the risk of matching non-numeric values (which you seem to have given the error you are getting).